# Problem embedding a custom framework inside an .app bundle with XCode 4

Tags: xcode, frameworks, ios-frameworks

I've been searching the web (and S.O.) for a while before asking this question. But I'm totally stuck and I don't know how to fix this.

I have to embed a custom framework inside an .app bundle, using XCode 4. I know I have to fix the install path of the framework using the `install_name_tool` utility. I've done it like this:

```
install_name_tool -change /Library/Frameworks/Ogg.framework/Versions/A/Ogg @executable_path/../Frameworks/Ogg.framework/Versions/A/Ogg <input framework>
```

I've verified that the framework was actually processed by looking at the "last modified" timestamp of the file.

Now the **problem**: the framework gets copied into the app bundle, but when I run the application, it crashes and in the error report it tells that `/Library/Frameworks/Ogg.framework/Versions/A/Ogg` image could not be found. Please note the wrong name.

I'm sure I'm embedding the right version of the framework (the one modified by `install_name_tool`).

What can I do? Thank you in advance.

**EDIT**: I even tried recompiling the library from sources, specifiying a different install path, but the problem persists. I've tried `otool -L` on the executable of my application, and it lists the Ogg framework with the wrong path (`/Library/Frameworks/....`). I don't know where it takes it. Please help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to run `install_name_tool` on the application's binary.

Or you can change the install name of the framework to `@executable_path/../<blah blah>` *before* you link the application to it.

Comment: Ok thanks!!! It worked!!! At first, I didn't follow the first advice: "You want to run install_name_tool on the application's binary.". Accepted